# Halide 'select' without evaluating both arguments

Tags: c++, select, arguments, ternary-operator, halide

As you can know if you tried Halide select(x,y,z); is something similar to the ternary operator on C++ where x is the conditional y if true and z if false.

Imagine that y is just return 0 and z is a really costly function, it could have sense to skip evaluating z where x is false, unfortunatly Halide evaluates both terms even if I set select(x,likely(y),z); or at least it happens if I use compile_to_file (.h + .lib)

Any idea about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the `likely` intrinsic is limited to loop peeling, not to anywhere a `select` might be used. That is, this only has an effect if the condition is closely related to the coordinates of the function definition in which the `select` appears (as in boundary conditions on an image, where the select is predicated on the x and y coordinates of the function). It does *not* turn arbitrary `select` expressions into full branching `if/else` statements.

You can see some examples in [the tests for the intrinsic](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/likely.cpp).

If you share an actual running piece of code it will be easier to discuss why loop peeling and the `likely` intrinsic do or don't apply in your particular case.