# How to prevent Halide 'select' from evaluating both branches

Tags: c++, select, conditional-operator, halide

The `select` expression in Halide is similar to `if` or `switch` statement in C. That is to say, the expression `select(cond, a, b)` will evaluate to `a` if `cond` is `true`, otherwise it evaluates to `b`.

So, I thought `select` evaluates only one branch between `a` and `b`, just like `if` does. But it turns out not true, I found `select` nearly always evaluates both branches. This is annoying especially when `a` or `b` is very costly. Maybe I'm not using Halide in the right way?

This problem was asked a long time ago in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911324/halide-select-without-evaluating-both-arguments), however the answer in that post cannot solve my problem. Here is some actual code:

```cpp
Var x("x"), y("y");
Func f("f"), g("g");
f(x, y) = x >= 10000;           // a1. f is calculated
// f(x, y) = cast<bool>(0);     // a2. f is constant
Expr power = pow(pow(x, x), y);
g(x, y) = select(f(x, y), power, 0.f);
f.compute_root();               // b1. compute f in advance
// f.compute_inline();          // b2. compute f inline

Buffer<float> result(1000, 1000);
g.realize(result);

double time = Tools::benchmark(3, 100, [&] {
    g.realize(result);
});
cout << "time: " << time * 1e3 << " ms" << endl;
```

In this example, `select` evaluates to `power`(a costly function) or `0.f` depending on `f(x, y)`. And `f(x, y)` always evaluates to `false`, which means `select` should always evaluates to `0.f`. There are some different test choices:

- a1: The value of `f` is calculated, and the result will always be `false`
- a2: `f` is set to the constant value `false`
- b1: Compute `f` in advance
- b2: Compute `f` inline

The test result (time cost) is:

- a1+b1: 4.22 ms
- a1+b2: 4.15 ms
- a2+b1: 4.15 ms
- a2+b2: 0.0788 ms

It seems clearly that `power` is evaluated in the first three cases, and it should not happen.

An other example is my [FAST corner detector](https://gist.github.com/mightbxg/adfc51d8d9bbfc4537d5c894e9bda20b). If the `threshold` is set to 256 (which can never be reached), `is_corner` will always be `false`. However, `select` in [L50](https://gist.github.com/mightbxg/adfc51d8d9bbfc4537d5c894e9bda20b#file-fastcorner-cpp-L50) always evaluates `score_val` (very time-consuming) unless `vectorize` in [L64](https://gist.github.com/mightbxg/adfc51d8d9bbfc4537d5c894e9bda20b#file-fastcorner-cpp-L64) is disabled.

Comment: I just found the description of `select` in Halide.h: "Returns an expression similar to the ternary operator in C, except that **it always evaluates all arguments**." So, is there any alternative solution?

Comment: I would be also interested in the select optimization you described. In CPU vectorized code (SSE2, AVX2, ..., without Halide), you can use [horizontal_or and horizontal_and instructions](https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/7f12a5899bcd3a8ae8e3f7814544e6661621da69/vectori256.h#L317) so that if all values of the vector meet some condition, you don't have to perform a costly branch for that vector at all.

Unfortunately, I haven't found anything like that in Halide yet. Maybe it can't be easily done for all Halide targets.